# Appdelegate sigabrt not appearing anything ! in main storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, appdelegate

I am making a newsfeed and when I try to add a post it appears this alert[SIGABRT]and not go to the next viewController to write the post here it's a picture , any idea?

[image: image of the mainstoryboard]

[image: second]

and those are some ss from the breakpoint and exception.

[image: breakpointimage]

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil )

            if user != nil {
                UserService.observeUserProfile(user!.uid) { UserProfile in
                    UserService.currentUserProfile = UserProfile
                }

                //
                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController

                self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            } else {
                UserService.currentUserProfile = nil

                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! ViewController

                self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Any `!` can crash the app. Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information.

Comment: When the exception occurs click on the continue button in the debug area (maybe multiple times) to get the exception reason.

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP.... it appears something like this in red

Comment: get output frames failed, state 8196

Comment: Actually there must be an output in the console and a stack trace.